# Replace expression using a tuple

Tags: replacement

Given an expression in `x`, `y`, `z` (for example), and a list with three elements, like `{1,2,3}`, how can I do the equivalent of `expr/.{x->1,y->2,z->3}`? So for example suppose

```
a = {1,2,3}
x^2+y^2+z^2 /.{x->1,y->2,z->3}
```

but obviously `x^2+y^2+z^2/.{x,y,z}->a` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 /. Rule @@@ Transpose[{{x, y, z}, a}]
```

You might also use `MapThread` and the like. But anyways, make sure you understand what `@@@` does.

Comment: Thanks. Beyond your suggestion to understand @@@, I also just learned that `->` is really infix shorthand for Rule[].

Answer (score 6):

This can be found in many answers, but I can't find the same question on this site or in the documentation. So:

```
x^2+y^2+z^2 /.Thread[{x, y, z} -> a]
  (* 14 *)
```